# Banned bitcoinj node ip

Tags: transactions, bitcoin-core, banscore

I've created many raw transactions today and after an hour I found out that my bitcoin node is only connected to 3 peers (testnet). Is it possible that my node has been banned due to wrong or double spent transactions? 
How long I will be banned?